Tensorflow incorrect derivative of the product of scalar and matrix
x - scalar, B - 2D tensor, f = xB (elementwise multiplication: f[i, j] = xB[i, j]).
Needed to compute the derivative of f with respect to x.
Tensorflow 2.17.0, 2.12.0
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as g:
    x = tf.Variable(np.random.uniform(size=(1,1)), dtype=tf.float64)
    B = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.normal(size=(5,5)), dtype=tf.float64)
    g.watch(x)
    g.watch(B)

    f = tf.multiply(B, x)

    gr = g.gradient(f, x)

Expected: gr.shape (5, 5)
Got: gr.shape (1, 1) (if I don't specify size in x, then gr.shape () ), in addition the value of gr is the same as the total sum of elements in B
Sanity check: f.shape (5, 5) (as expected)

Shape of gr is expected to be (5, 5), however it is (1, 1) . That is the problem

Hi @Yose , This is the approach that you can use ,You can now calculate ‘f’ as the element wise product of ‘x’ and ‘B’.
Differentiate with the respect to ‘x’ the sum total of all elements of matrix ‘f’.
This gradient should be used to have the understanding that the gradient of each element of ‘f’ with respect to ‘x’ is ‘B’.

@Sagar, "the gradient of each element of 'f' with respect to 'x' is 'B' " is what I expect, however the result I get is not 'B' but a total sum of its elements, which, generally, is a different thing
